# How to attach a content script to single tab?

Tags: javascript, sdk, mozilla

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs[0].on('open', function(tab) {
worker = tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.min.js"), data.url("pagemod.js")]
});
});
```

.when trying to use worker to send smth to scriptFile, like:
     worker.port.emit("doSmth", "message")
i have an error "worker is undefined"... there is a syntax problem, i guess.

Comment: now i am using pagemod for these script files, but these scripts also attaches to each new tab.. that`s bad.

Comment: tags used for this question are extremely generic. `sdk` and `mozilla` are pretty much meaningless . Assuming this is something to do with browser add-on or extension code you may want to tag it more appropriately